# ubuntu 15.04 python module telnetlib

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip, mod-python

I need some help with my new Ubuntu 15.04 VM. I tryied to install the pip module telnetlib3 but I got some errors:

`pip install telnetlib3
Downloading/unpacking telnetlib3
  Downloading telnetlib3-0.2.3.tar.gz (96kB): 96kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-YojtJ4/telnetlib3/setup.py) egg_info for package telnetlib3
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-YojtJ4/telnetlib3/setup.py", line 28, in <module>`
        `install_requires = [str(req.req) for req in requirements]
      File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 72, in parse_requirements
        "parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: "
    TypeError: parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: 'session'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "<string>", line 17, in <module>`

`File "/tmp/pip-build-YojtJ4/telnetlib3/setup.py", line 28, in <module>`

```
install_requires = [str(req.req) for req in requirements]
```

`File "/home/max/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_file.py", line 72, in parse_requirements`

```
"parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: "
```

`TypeError: parse_requirements() missing 1 required keyword argument: 'session'`

`----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-YojtJ4/telnetlib3
Storing debug log for failure in /home/max/.pip/pip.log`

I alredy googled it but I don´t find anything useful for me.

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: What do you really want to do? Unless you are writing a terminal emulator, I think you should look for other networking libraries that Python offers.

Comment: I want to capture snmp with it. Do you know a lib I could use?

Comment: SNMP is usually using UDP. Telnet is using TCP. What do you mean by capturing SNMP? If you need a network capture you can use `pcapy`, `pypcap` or `scapy`. Can you give more details what you really want to achieve?

Comment: I mixed somethin up. I´m follwing the gns3 academy course of Python Network Automation and I want to install all moduls I need for it. So I need to install the telnetlib.

Comment: Where did you install `pip` from? (I was having issues with pip on 15.04, fixed only when I installed the very-bloody-latest version straight from *github*)

Comment: I installed it from apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem on OSX and managed to fix it, i thought i should share the fix for anyone that runs into this problem. It seems a session argument is needed by the parse_requirements() function. This worked for me:

Download the libtelnet3 package manually:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/telnetlib3/telnetlib3-0.2.3.tar.gz#md5=964a2f7f9b1b0b7f9024942fa413fc94
```

extract the tarball:

```
tar -zxvf telnetlib3-0.2.3.tar.gz
```

Go into the newly created folder:

```
cd telnetlib3-0.2.3
```

Open setup.py in your favourite editor to line 27:

```
vi setup.py +27
```

Look for this line:

```
requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(here, 'requirements.txt'))
```

And change it to:

```
requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(here, 'requirements.txt'), session=False)
```

Save the file and run setup.py:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Not sure if this will work for any system, but it did for me, good luck ;)